# How to create a submenu in the sidebar

Tags: html

I'm trying to create this type of submenu for social in the sidebar [url](http://t-phys.web.nitech.ac.jp/sidebar.html).The options for social submenu are : fb,twitter,youtube.

My html :

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/abc">abc<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-upload"></span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/System">System<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span>
        </a></li>
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/web">Web<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/social">Social<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here I'm trying to create a submenu for social.social should be a dropdownlist with 3 options.Onclick of one option in the social dropdown,should redirect to other page.

How can I do this over here? can anyone please help me out regarding this.

Comment: Can anyone please help me out in creating a submenu in a side-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```js
$('.sidebar-nav li a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
.sidebar-nav{list-style:none; width:200px;}
.sub-menu{padding:0; display:none; list-style:none;}
.sidebar-nav li.active ul{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar">
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/abc">abc<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-upload"></span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/System">System<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span>
        </a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/web">Web<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span></a></li>
        <li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/social">Social<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-hdd-o"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
  </li>
<li class="sub-sidebar-brand"><a href="#/abc">abc<span
                class="sub_icon fa fa-upload"></span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Please refer the url that I had edited in the question.And I'm trying to create the same type of submenu over here

Comment: add some css check answer

Comment: Its working fine.But,instead of hover,onclick of a System should display the submenu options.How can we do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for React

Replace the material icon with an image

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { css } from "@emotion/core";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown";

const MenuItem = (props) => {
  const {
    page,
    isSubMenu = false,
    onClick,
    isActive = false,
    showArrow,
  } = props;



const { name, icon } = page;

  return (
    <MenuItem.Wrapper
      isActive={isActive}
      isSubMenu={isSubMenu}
      onClick={() => onClick(page)}
    >
      <Icon>{icon}</Icon>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
        <span className="name-holder">{name}</span>
        {showArrow && <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
      </div>
    </MenuItem.Wrapper>
  );
};

MenuItem.Wrapper = styled.span`
  font-size: 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 24px 24px 0;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  .name-holder {
    margin-left: 2rem;
  }
  .show-arrow {
    display: none;
  }
  &:hover {
    background-color: #f7c948;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  ${(props) =>
    props.isSubMenu &&
    css`
      padding-left: 20px;
    `}

  ${(props) =>
    props.isActive &&
    css`
      background-color: #f7c948;
      cursor: pointer;
    `}
`;

const SubMenu = (props) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const { icon, name, pages, onSubMenuClick } = props;

  const itemPage = {
    name,
    icon,
    link: "",
  };

  const currentLocation = window.location.pathname;

  console.log("currentLocation:", currentLocation);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MenuItem
        page={itemPage}
        showArrow
        onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}
      />

      <SubMenu.Wrapper visible={visible}>
        {pages.map((page, index) => (
          <MenuItem
            isActive={currentLocation === page.link}
            key={index}
            isSubMenu
            page={page}
            onClick={onSubMenuClick}
          />
        ))}
      </SubMenu.Wrapper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

SubMenu.Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  ${(props) =>
    props.visible &&
    css`
      max-height: 500px;
      transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
    `}
`;

const SideBarHandler = (props) => {
  const { pages } = props;
  const history = useHistory();
  const currentLocation = window.location.pathname;
  const menuItemClickHandler = (page) => history.push(page.link);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="items">
        {pages.map((page, index) => {
          const { name, icon, submenu } = page;

          return submenu === undefined ? (
            <MenuItem
              isActive={currentLocation.includes(page.link)}
              page={page}
              key={index}
              onClick={menuItemClickHandler}
            />
          ) : (
            <SubMenu
              onSubMenuClick={menuItemClickHandler}
              key={page.name}
              name={name}
              icon={icon}
              pages={submenu}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBarHandler;
```